How to make ports listening with the ncat command in a script since i always times out?
This is the script opening multiple ports. However without me doing a single thing it times out after a while. How can i make the scripts stay open indefinitely or atleast for a long time. Would adding '-w 3hours' after the ncat command do the trick (to make the script continue to execute for 3 hours)?
for port in 10001 10002 10003; do ncat -l $port & done

If i change it to include -w such as do ncat -w 14400 -l $port. It is unhappy and ncat says this:
Ncat: Since April 2010, the default unit for -w timeout is 
seconds, so your time of "14400" is 240.0 minutes. Use "14400ms" 
for 14400 milliseconds. QUITTING.

Before then quitting, why is it such a big deal if it is 240 minutes?

Nevermind, it appears as though -w is ignored when used with -l. I think something else is making the connection drop, just simply for port in 10001 10002 10003; do ncat -l $port & done, in theory, should idle forever.

I'm not sure what's the deal with ncat dropping the connection after a while, however, as I mentioned in the comments section of my answer, there are multiple implementations of Netcat available, one of them is nc, which is installed by default. Run man nc to understand exactly how to run it, options will likely be similar, you may have better luck. However I'd leave this question opened, as I'm too interested in what could be causing the drop.

Alright Thank you.
